# WordPress: How to add CSS class to the menu links generated by the following code

Tags: css, wordpress, hyperlink

```
<?php 
 wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'mainnav', 'menu_class' => 'nav-bar-content     current', 'menu_id' => 'navigation', 'container' => false, '      theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'show_home' => '1')); 
?>
```

This code is in my header file and I am implementing it in WORDPRESS, and the code is generating unordered list in which we have list items having links like

```
<a href = "">
```

I want to add my own CSS class to this link that is like

```
<a class = "some class" href = "">
```

Thanks in advance if anyone could help me out?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select "Screen Options" from the top right of the page..
2. Then under "Show advanced menu properties" click "CSS Classes"
3. Now add the classes to the menu items within the WP menu structure window.

Here is a link to the WP Advanced Menu Settings page. https://en.support.wordpress.com/advanced-menu-settings/

Then in your functions add this.

```
function my_walker_nav_menu_start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    $class= $item->classes['0'];
    $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="'.$class.'"', $item_output, 1);
    return $item_output;
 }
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'my_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 10, 4);
```

Now add the CSS classes to the menu items and that function will output the class in the anchor.

Comment: Thanks the information is helpfull but I want to add CSS to the hyperlink, neither to the ul nor to the li.

Comment: Updated my answer. Let me know if it works @HarshwardhanSinghRathore